# MongoDB.NET Driver query for $lte and $gte throwing error: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

```cs
FilterDefinition<DM.Content> filterDefinition = Builders<DM.Content>.Filter.Empty;
filterDefinition &= Builders<DM.Content>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsDeleted, false);
if (contentTypeId > 0)
{
    if (contentTypeId == 4)// Photo Video recipes
    {
        filterDefinition &= Builders<DM.Content>.Filter.In(x => x.ContentTypeId, new List<int>() { 1, 2 });// Video Photo recipes Recipes
    }
    else
    {
        filterDefinition &= Builders<DM.Content>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ContentTypeId, contentTypeId);
    }
}
// rating
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rating))
{

    //filterDefinition &= Builders<DM.Content>.Filter.Gte(x => x.ContentAverageRating, rating);
    filterDefinition &= new BsonDocument("$expr", new BsonDocument("$gte",
        new BsonArray {
            new BsonDocument("$toDouble", "$ContentAverageRating"),
            Convert.ToDouble(rating)
        }));

}
// cookTime
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookTime))
{

    filterDefinition &= new BsonDocument("$expr", new BsonDocument("$lte",
        new BsonArray {
            new BsonDocument("$toDouble", "$ContentTime"),
            Convert.ToDouble(cookTime)
        }));
}


SortDefinition<DM.Content> sortDefinition = Builders<DM.Content>.Sort.Descending(x => x.UpdatedDate);
var results = await contentDocument.AggregateByPage(filterDefinition, sortDefinition, pageIndex, pageSize);
return new DM.CustomModels.ContentSearchResult() { ContentItems = results.data.ToList(), TotalPages = results.totalPages };
```

```cs
public static async Task<(int totalPages, IReadOnlyList<TDocument> data)> AggregateByPage<TDocument>(
    this IMongoCollection<TDocument> collection,
    FilterDefinition<TDocument> filterDefinition,
    SortDefinition<TDocument> sortDefinition,
    int page,
    int pageSize)
{
    var countFacet = AggregateFacet.Create("count",
        PipelineDefinition<TDocument, AggregateCountResult>.Create(new[]
        {
            PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Count<TDocument>()
        }));

    var dataFacet = AggregateFacet.Create("data",
        PipelineDefinition<TDocument, TDocument>.Create(new[]
        {
            PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Sort(sortDefinition),
            PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Skip<TDocument>((page - 1) * pageSize),
            PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Limit<TDocument>(pageSize),
        }));


    var aggregation = await collection.Aggregate()
        .Match(filterDefinition)
        .Facet(countFacet, dataFacet)
        .ToListAsync();

    var count = aggregation.First()
        .Facets.First(x => x.Name == "count")
        .Output<AggregateCountResult>()?
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .Count ?? 0;

    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)count / pageSize);

    var data = aggregation.First()
        .Facets.First(x => x.Name == "data")
        .Output<TDocument>();

    return (totalPages, data);
}
```

I am trying to execute the above query to check ContentAverageRating, ContentTime with certain conditions. But throwing an exception:

> Command aggregate failed: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gte: [ { $toDouble: "$ContentAverageRating" }, 3.0 ], $lte: [ { $toDouble: "$ContentTime" }, 15.0 ] }.

Can anyone let me know what is wrong with the above query?

Comment: Try change `$and` to `$expr` in your first `filterDefinition`.

Comment: I had tried that too, didn't work.

Comment: Are you using `.Find()` or `.Aggregate()`? Try to provide complete code to reproduce the error (start from `FilterDefinition`, until last step run the query). And also try to provide sample document. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Yong Please do check now. I has provided entire code

Comment: Look like `AggregateByPage` method is custom method. Please show the implementation as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yong I has added AggregateByPage Method. please check

Answer (score 0):

### Issue & Concern

From what I suspect, MongoDB .Net driver had placed both `$gte` and `$lte` under the same `$expr` value, which make the whole BsonDocument failed.

Expected generated Bson Document

```
{ 
  $and: [
    { $expr: { $gte: [/* Match Condition */] } },
    { $expr: { $lte: [/* Match Condition */] } }
  ] 
}
```

Actual generated Bson Doccument

```
{ 
  $and: [
    { $expr: { $gte: [/* Match Condition */], $lte: [/* Match Condition */] } }
  ] 
}
```

[image]

---

### Solution

After some trial and error, I suggest that remove the BsonDocument with `$expr` from both `$lte` and `$gte`. Then you create another `FilterDefinition`, `rootFilterDefinition`to place `$expr` at top level, then append the `filterDefinition` as below:

```cs
filterDefinition &= 
    new BsonDocument("$gte",
        new BsonArray {
            new BsonDocument("$toDouble", "$ContentAverageRating"),
            Convert.ToDouble(rating)
        }
    );

filterDefinition &= 
    new BsonDocument("$lte",
        new BsonArray {
            new BsonDocument("$toDecimal", "$ContentTime"),
            Decimal.Parse(cookTime)
        }
    );

FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> rootFilterDefinition = new BsonDocument("$expr", 
    filterDefinition.ToBsonDocument());

var results = await contentDocument.AggregateByPage(rootFilterDefinition , sortDefinition, pageIndex, pageSize);
```

Equivalent to this MongoDB query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              {
                $toDouble: "$ContentAverageRating"
              },
              3.0
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              {
                $toDouble: "$ContentTime"
              },
              15.0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kEfY55YMmF1)

Comment: I had tried this, but not getting the expected results

Comment: Try to write a query and run it in MongoDB compass, to check whether your query works correctly that querying the expected result or not.